# May I edit and view the global var in the code via test case

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I use Jest to write some test case.
The JavaScript file which I need to test has some global variables, and I want to get and set the value of these global variables. I tried to export the global variables and use the in test.js directly. However, it not works. There is a simple code:

simple.js:

```
    var someGlobalVariable = '';
    //Basic Function with no return type
    function firstFunction() {
        someGlobalVariable = 'hello';
    }
    //Function which returns String
    function secondFunction() {
        //firstFunction();
        console.log(someGlobalVariable);
        return someGlobalVariable;
    }

    module.exports.firstFunction= firstFunction;
    module.exports.secondFunction = secondFunction;
    module.exports.someGlobalVariable = someGlobalVariable;
```

simple.test.js:
     const jstester = require ('./Test');

```
    test('secondFunction', ()=>{
        //jstester.firstFunction();
        jstester.someGlobalVariable = 'world';
        console.log(jstester.someGlobalVariable);
        expect(jstester.secondFunction()).toMatch('world');
    });
```

The result is:

```
    FAIL  ./Test.test.js
    ✕ secondFunction (19ms)

    ● secondFunction

    expect(received).toMatch(expected)

    Expected value to match:
        "world"
    Received:
        ""

   5 |     jstester.someGlobalVariable = 'world';
   6 |     console.log(jstester.someGlobalVariable);
>  7 |     expect(jstester.secondFunction()).toMatch('world');
     |                                       ^
   8 | });
   9 |
  10 |

  at Object.toMatch (Test.test.js:7:39)

  console.log Test.test.js:6
      world

  console.log Test.js:12

  Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
  Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
  Snapshots:   0 total
  Time:        0.961s, estimated 1s
  Ran all test suites.
```

The someGlobalVariable in simple.js still is ". But I want simple.test.js change the value to "world".

Is there a way to change the value directly? Or I have to add set and get function in simple.js?

Comment: This link may help you : https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure on your use case, but I do have a few suggestions:

1. **Change `someGlobalVariable` to an object and mutate it directly. The solution would be something like:**

simple.js:

```
var someGlobalVariable = {
  value: "hello"
};
//Basic Function with no return type
function firstFunction() {
  someGlobalVariable.value = "hello";
}
//Function which returns String
function secondFunction() {
  //firstFunction();
  console.log(someGlobalVariable.value);
  return someGlobalVariable.value;
}

module.exports.firstFunction = firstFunction;
module.exports.secondFunction = secondFunction;
module.exports.someGlobalVariable = someGlobalVariable;
```

simple.test.js:

```
const jstester = require("./simple");
test("secondFunction", () => {
  //jstester.firstFunction();
  jstester.someGlobalVariable.value = "world";
  console.log(jstester.someGlobalVariable.value);
  expect(jstester.secondFunction()).toMatch("world");
});
```

This works because you aren't changing the reference to the subject, you're just simply changing the property while the underlying reference is the same.

2. **Have `secondFunction` receive a variable with the original `someGlobalVariable` as the default value:**

   function secondFunction(dependency = someGlobalVariable) {
       //firstFunction();
       console.log(someGlobalVariable);
       return someGlobalVariable;
   }

This way you can pass arbitrary values to `secondFunction` and test your specific cases. However, this doesn't mutate the global variable inside `simple.js`.

Hope this helpers! Cheers :)